# Question Timeline View Counter

Tags: feature-request, timeline

By chance, I found the link to the timeline of a given question/answer or more general post:

http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/[enterYourPostIdHere]/timeline

The thing itself is cool enough (and I wonder what other secrets are hidden), but it would be even cooler, if it would contain a view counter, that prints the current number of views, when the post is changed.

Comment: The same feature request was posted at meta.SO: [Add a link to the timeline of a post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126447/add-a-link-to-the-timeline-of-a-post).

Comment: and here is the [list-of-unlinked-pages-on-stack-exchange-sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/76566/178818)

Comment: and two more: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/feeds/question/4805  and  http://math.stackexchange.com/feeds/user/19341. Ok they are linked, but very hard to recognize...